# How to add a file from a filefield in Django to urls and views?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-uploads

I'm doing a Django project, and I have a model called *Projects*, in this model I have a FileField inwhich files get uploaded to /media/files/YEAR/MONTH/DATE/.

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

models.py:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='files/%Y/%m/%d', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, default='')
```

template:

```
...
{% if project.file_upload %}
<tr>
  <td>File</td>
  <td><a href="{{ project.file_upload.url }}">{{ project.file_upload.name }} (Size: {{ project.file_upload.size|filesizeformat }})</a></td>
</tr>
{% endif %}
...
```

Now a link to a file would be something like: */media/files/2016/05/25/picture.png* or */media/files/2016/05/25/report.pdf*

Currently I get a 404 page not found, whenever I click the link. That is ofcourse because the path is not in the *urls.py*, but since you usually add a view to an url, I don't know how you would do it with a single file, as it would seem to me a view wouldn't be necessary.

How do I tell Django in urls (And possibly in views) how to get that file? I want to be able to click the link and then either view the picture/pdf in the browser or simply download the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does not serve static files. To force these files to be served when `DEBUG=True`, add this code to `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

(from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

You do not need to tell Django about static files in `views.py`

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I used changed your code to media_url and media_root. I hoped there was a better way to do it. But I guess this will have to do. How will this work with Debug=False though?

Comment: When debug is false, you will need a specialized server to serve media files, static files and the admin site files. An example server would be lighttpd.